# LocationManager still lives when switching tab

Tags: cllocationmanager

I have a TabBarApplication with four tab bar items.

My third tab uses a CLLocationManager to locate where the user are and so forth.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {

[locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
NSLog(@"error%@",error);
switch([error code])
{
    case kCLErrorNetwork:
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Please check your network connection or that you are not in airplane mode." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }
        break;
    case kCLErrorDenied:{
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"You have denied to allow Berns to get your location. " delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }
        break;
    default:
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Unknown network error." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }
        break;
}
```

}

But when I switch tab to the fourth, this happends:

I get an UIAlertView with the message:

```
Unknown network error.
```

Doesn't the CLLocationManager die when switching tab?
I have called [release]-method in the dealloc-method.

Comment: I don't know why this happened. But it haven't happened again since I posted this thread, so it had be something else...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it had to do with that I didn't implemented Reachability to check for network connection.

This is also a demand in the App Store Guidelines (or what you call it).

So the answer is: *Check for Internet connection with Reachability and inform the user if the application demands this.*

Answer (score 0):

```
**use this in dealloc method**

-(void)dealloc
{

  [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];

locationManager.delegate=nil;

[locationManager release];
}

//...........cheers.
```